# Irregular UV unwrap from rectangular object

Tags: uv

I have made the following model by manipulating the standard cube. When I finished, I used Ctrl-A in Object Mode (like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14524/non-uniform-scaling-during-uv-unwrap-what-is-this) question suggests) to normalize the overall scaling to 1. However, after marking my seams and unwrapping, I get the UV pattern as shown below. I used the plain "Unwrap" command.

All of the seams and edges appear correct, but I'd like all the edges to be orthogonal to each other and not "skewed" on the grid. What can I do to fix this?

[image: here]

[image: this]

Comment: After you unwrap try to open operator menu using F6 button and change method to Conformal. Also you may need to add more seams and avoid N-gons on the mesh.

Comment: See [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35203/why-does-blender-warp-uv-pelt-when-unwrapping-tight-geometry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, I used the Conformal unwrap method. Thanks @Denis.

[image]