# Unwrapping beveled cube

Tags: mesh, uv, edges

I don't unwrap my models very often so I decided I would give unwrapping this simple box-like shape a go. I beveled the edges and corners and tried my best to mark the seams (see below).
[image: Here's how my box currently looks; the red lines indicate where I marked the seams.]

I then decided to unwrap the model on a 1024 x 1024 texture, but as you can see below some of the edges are a bit wonky looking (see below).
[image: This is how the UV unwrap results look. Edges are uneven.]

What should I do to prevent wonky edges? If anybody has any advice or tips I will be most grateful.

Comment: Select two vertices on the top edge of the inner face, scale them to 0, Hit "P" to pin them. Repeat for bottom edge. Do the same with vertical edges, scale with X to 0. then you can unwrap  again to fit the beveled faces or scale them the same way, whatever suits you better.

Comment: I selected the top edge of the inner face and did as you said but upon scaling them to 0 they both merge into the median point; was I supposed to scale it to 0 on the Y axis?

Comment: Yes, scale by the axis. Solution you've came up with is probably ok, but depending on situation it might be texture editing hell.

Comment: This could be caused by tiny long quads of the bevel which sometimes make Angle Based unwrapping fail. Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35203/why-does-blender-warp-uv-pelt-when-unwrapping-tight-geometry.

Comment: @MrZak I see! Is there a way around that?

Comment: If you don't mean a workaround to be [straightening UV map](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41132/how-do-i-straighten-uv-maps) then it seems to be only using Conformal-based unwrapping method (which doesn't appear to be intended to be used instead of Angle-Based, rather than in some cases).

Comment: @MrZak Darn I wish I had thought of that sooner.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of thinking I decided to try something different. I performed a Smart UV project and made the most important area of the mesh the largest, since this model will be low poly. I could have managed my space a little better but I think it looks okay.

[image: The face on the top right is the most important, thus the largest.]

Comment: When making a UV map, it is desirable to have as few seams as possible, I don't think this is an ideal solution.

Comment: @veryRandomMe You're right, it does look a bit messy. I may give it another try soon.