# What is the technical difference between conformal and angle-based unwrapping?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

When unwrapping an object, there are two options for the *Method* to use: *Conformal*, and *Angle Based*.  What is the technical difference between these two methods?

[image]

I usually leave it at Angle Based, but sometimes that [distorts tight geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35203/why-does-blender-warp-uv-pelt-when-unwrapping-tight-geometry?lq=1) and I switch to conformal.  So basically I just blindly see which looks better project by project, I am interested in how they work.

***Note:*** I am aware of [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/238/5705) and [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/241/5705), but that more addresses the use of the two methods, I am looking for the technical difference.

Answer (score 1):

**Conformal**
Uses LSCM (Least Squared Conformal Mapping). This usually gives a less accurate UV mapping than Angle Based, but works better for simpler objects.
(As describled by blender user manual)

Attached is the link to the White paper on LSCM

http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Fall09/Levy02.pdf
http://alice.loria.fr/publications/papers/2002/lscm/lscm.pdf

Comment: [Please avoid link-only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).  Someone should be able to find an answer to the question from reading your answer without going anywhere else or reading any 10-page paper.  I specifically asked for the technical difference between the two methods.  (BTW, your two links are to the same document.)

Comment: Well technical as it is, the answer isn't a short one so I thought future questions of such nature could be addressed through understanding those technical papers. The reason why there were 2 links is that if one fails there is another one to it. And the topic cannot be easily addressed in one post anyhow "technically".